# would it be possible add attributes to an anonymous class instead only overwrite its methods?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I was wondering if is possible to add properties to an annonymous class in JAVA?, maby is an easy question but the trick here is that I saw some codes on google that were doing it but when I tried in Netbeans it didn't happened.

I created an instance of the class in the annonymous way but instead of overriding the method i add other and a variable and the instance was an simple, in google others dudes made this classes all on the fly an I couldn't why?

```
 public class Cat(){ 
 public void sayMew(){}
 }
 Cat gato = new Cat{
  @Override
  public void sayMew(){System.out.println("mew"); 
 };   
 gato.sayMew(); //This works fine.

 //Some code over there do this and it didn't work for me:
 Cat gato = new Cat(){
  int legs = 4;
  public void scratch(){System.out.println("scratch"); 
 };   
//Even I saw this king of instances be pointed by variables types :/ what 
am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define new methods or fields inside anonymous class in Java, but when you are assigning that anonymous class definition to the parent class type you won't be able to call the new method defined in the anonymous class or access the new field through the parent class reference.

When you do something like this:

```
Cat gato = new Cat() {
    int legs = 4;
    public void scratch() {
         System.out.println("scratch");
    }
}
```

You are actually extending the `Cat` class with an anonymous class, then you are defining new methods in that anonymous child class. Now as you are assigning the child class instance to the parent class reference, the new methods cannot be invoked through the parent class reference as the parent class doesn't know about them.

To invoke it you need to call it immediately:

```
new Cat() {
    int legs = 4;
    public void scratch() {
         System.out.println("scratch");
    }
}.scratch();
```

So you can define new methods or fields in the anonymous child class, but can't call them through the parent reference, either you use them internally or call them directly (as I demonstrated).

Generally anonymous classes would override the parent class methods or implement an interface inline. Pre Java 8 functional interfaces could be implemented through anonymous class, after Java 8 they are mostly done through lambda expressions.

Comment: If the `scratch()` method can be called on the object created in your second code block, then is that object not actually of type `Cat`?

Comment: @MihirKekkar that object would be a sub-class of `Cat`, so you can use Cat's API as well the methods you defined on your anonymous class.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I guess I learned something new from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

More of an addendum, as that other answer isn't 100% complete:

> You can define new methods or fields inside anonymous class in Java, but when you are assigning that anonymous class definition to the parent class type you won't be able to call the new method defined in the anonymous class or access the new field through the parent class reference.

This is correct, but since Java 10, we have the `var` keyword:

```
var cat = new Cat() { int legs = 4; ...
```

**Now** the compiler knows: not only did you create that anonymous inner class, but now the compiler knows that `cat` is an instance of that **inner** class. Before that, you could **only** denote that instance of the inner class using a `Cat` reference. Now you can use something that *knows* that this is "more" than an ordinary cat. Thus, with java 10 and `var` you can now do `System.out.println(cat.legs)` **outside** of that inner class! There is now a way to denote that inner class instance that keeps track of its real nature!

And that is actually of value of in the real world, see [this](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue263.html) for example:

> Henri Tremblay used this trick nicely to simulate the idea of tuples in Java, using anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code isn't compile. To declare class you should not use parenthesis.

Suppose your concrete class `Cat` like this.

```
class Cat {
    void meow() {
        System.out.println("I'm a cat!");
    };
}
```

And you could instantiate anonymus class like this

```
Cat cat = new Cat() {
    int lives = 9;

    @Override
    void meow() {
        super.meow();
        System.out.printf("And I have %s lives!", lives);
    }
};

cat.meow();
//prints:   
//I'm a cat!
//And I have 9 lives!
```